# Regular Expression for Text Area for validating Range

Tags: regex

i want regular expression for Text Area which will validate the not more than 200 characters inside text area, as we know the max length property is not working for textarea.

i am having regular expression but they are not working for enter key

1. `@"^([\w]|[\W]|[\n]){0,200}$"`
2. `@"^([\s]|[\S]|[\n]){0,200}$"`
3. `@"^([\w]|[\W]|[\r\n]){0,200}$"`
4. `@"^([\s]|[\S]|[\r\n]){0,200}$"`

tried all the validators but still  not working for enter 
please help me i that.

Comment: What language? JavaScript?

Comment: .net regular expression validator

Comment: Why not using `String.Length` method?

Comment: you mean custom validator??

Answer (score 0):

If your language doesn't support the dotall flag, a simple workaround is to use a pair of opposites in a character class.

This should work in all regex flavours:

```
^[\s\S]{0,200}$
```

To count one enter press on windows ad one "character":

```
^(\r\n|.){0,200}$
```

Regex alternation will match left-to-right, so the windows newline pair will be consumed as a single term and count as 1 of the 200 allowed.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: if i am typing 200 character while typing if i gave one enter then it is showing me error . out of range .   if i am typing 199 character and while typing if i gave one enter then it is working

Comment: Isn't that what you want? Or do you not want to count trailing line feeds? Or do you not want to count *any* line feeds?

Comment: i want to count the newline and with that my regular expression should not fail.

Comment: It's because you are using windows and one enter press is **two** characters: `\r\n`. To count one enter press as one "character", see edits.

Comment: your edited regex is fail if i am pressing a enter i want to keep account of enters . means one enter as on character count . so if i am having 198 character and 2 time press enter that means 198 character plus 2 enters which is 200 it should valid for range 0 to 200.